# markdown preview in gedit

Tags: gedit, markdown

I've found a [plugin](https://github.com/jpfleury/gedit-markdown) to preview markdown in gedit. But I am not sure if it is backdated. Is there any other better option for previewing markdown in gedit?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation in the https://github.com/jpfleury/gedit-markdown repository has Gedit 3.10 as the highest version.

We can try to launch it on modern Ubuntu. For example on 16.04 LTS with Gedit 3.18.

```
sudo apt-get install gedit python3-markdown
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://github.com/jpfleury/gedit-markdown/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
cd gedit-markdown-master
./gedit-markdown.sh install
gedit
```

then enable plugin in the *Preferences → Plugins → Markdown Preview*, but it will not work because of changed API. The error here is shown below:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "/home/user/.local/share/gedit/plugins/markdown-preview/__init__.py", line 113, in do_activate
>    self.addMarkdownPreviewTab()
>  File "/home/user/.local/share/gedit/plugins/markdown-preview/__init__.py", line 139, in addMarkdownPreviewTab
>    panel.add_item(self.scrolledWindow, "MarkdownPreview", _("Markdown Preview"), image)
> AttributeError: 'Stack' object has no attribute 'add_item'
> ```

So I would recommend to use [ReText](https://github.com/retext-project/retext) as a replacement:

> [image: official screenshot of ReText]

You can install it as simple `sudo apt install retext`. For spell check you need to install additional package with `sudo apt install python3-enchant`. It has two modes of operation - Live Preview and Preview.

Note: if you need to have latest version of ReText on old systems as 16.04 LTS, then you can install it from Python Packages with `pip3 install ReText`.

---

I have just hacked it to work with Pluma (fork of Gedit for [MATE DE](http://mate-desktop.org/)) in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
All you need is to install dependencies from APT and then use files from my [Github repository](https://github.com/N0rbert/pluma-markdown):

```
sudo apt-get install pluma python-markdown gir1.2-webkit-3.0 python-configparser -y

cd ~/Downloads
wget https://github.com/N0rbert/pluma-markdown/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
cd pluma-markdown-master
./pluma-markdown.sh install
```

and it will look like:

> [image: pluma-markdown on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (preview in bottom)]

You can move preview to the side by editing ini-file:

```
sed -i 's/panel = bottom/panel = side/' ~/.config/pluma/pluma-markdown.ini
```

> [image: pluma-markdown on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (preview in side)]

Note: this solution with `pluma-markdown` will not work for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (because of missed python integration for pluma). And it will not work on newer versions because of upgrade to WebKit2.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Retex is not a solution for gedit though.

Comment: @ArafatHasan If you have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS - then you can use Pluma with fork on `gedit-markdown`. See last part of my answer.